# MVC: Is a custom UITableViewCell a view or controller or both?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, model-view-controller

I used to consider a `CustomUITableViewCell.xib` as the view and the corresponding `CustomUITableViewCell.swift` class as the controller of a table view cell.

Is this correct? A youtube video I stumbled upon considers the class as the view: https://youtu.be/n06RE9A_8Ks?t=177

**Edit:**
To clarify the question: Which one of the following is the view and controller? Are both considered the view?

- `CustomUITableViewCell.xib`
- `CustomUITableViewCell.swift`

Answer (score 1):

I'd absolutely consider it a "view" (in terms of MVC).  It's of the group of logic that (along with the .xib) handles 1 particular view of information, rather than orchestrating some aspect of the general logic of the app.

I also consider a UIViewController as belonging to the "view" part of MVC for the same reason.  Of course, if you put far more business logic into your view controllers than that which is necessary to support the single view, then your view controller is some mix of MVC.  For example, if your view controller chooses what scene of the app comes next, your view controller then participates in controller logic and it's not really following MVC.  Your view controller is forced to do a lot of single view-related work, though, because there's a single view it's responsible for and that the view-work is more practically done in the UIViewController rather than the UIView.

So when you ask about a cell view class's stance in MVC, if it's doing single view work, then it's a "View".  If you mix in controller work or model work, then you've muddied up the separation of responsibilities that MVC espouses.

Comment: If it handles the view logic, shouldn't it be considered a controller then? As for my understanding the view is the generic part that gets adjusted by the controller, i.e. the `CustomUITableViewCell.swift` class file.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):  Components
    The model is ...
    A view can be any output representation of information, such as a chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view for accountants.
    The third part or section, the controller, accepts input and converts it to commands for the model or view.

Comment: Also, if your code is taking input (from user, or from network, or sensors or from other views and processing it, and then orchestrating what should happen in other views or networking or to change model data, etc... then this code is of the Controller of MVC.   If instead some code is focused purely on one view (one screen, or one area of a screen, or one UIView or table cell or whatever) regardless of if this code is within a UIView or a UIViewController or .xib or wherever else, then this code is of the View of MVC.  So then study your classes - decide how mixed up they are against MVC. :)

Comment: And as a general rule of thumb with MVC : make sure your views are stupid. They only get to know about that view.  They don't interact with the model, or the networking, or the other sensors, or the business logic of the app.  In true MVC, they would define a way to have them be fed the data to be populated inside them, and they'd define a way to communicate actions that occurred within them.  These APIs would be used by the Controller layer of the app as part of its orchestration of all the other Views and Models.  Few write such pure & strict MVC, though...

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion it is a view.  It should be handling only UI components in the class.  Think of both files as a complete view.  One cannot be without the other.  Thus I consider them one.